Rotate an object around its origin with an arbitrary (imported) global axis. Do it while keyframing. Do not rotate around root's origin
Can someone explain how to do this, rotate around an object's origin, not the root object, Rotate objects around their origin along a global axis (scripted) without bpy.ops but do it in terms of keyframing.  This involves importing keyframes (interpolators).

if you want an answer in python you should add the tag python to your question.
